# Why can I no longer log into BitBucket from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: bitbucket, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with BitBucket Extensions installed.
For some reason I can no longer log into BitBucket from Visual Studio.
It's giving me an "Invalid Credentials" error.

I am using the same username (email address) and password that I use to log into the BitBucket website.

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the BitBucket extension.
I tried changing my password.

For some reason I can no longer log into BitBucket to push/pull from my remote branch.
This has been working fine for 6 months. I am not sure what has changed.

Comment: Does this help? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-extension-for-visual-studio-not-allowing-to-login/qaq-p/1200694 seems that an App password can fix this.

Comment: @Arson0 - What is the difference between "BitBucket Cloud" and "BitBucket Server"? I tried googling this and found the answers confusing. Which should I be using given that my repository is hosted on BitBucket.Org? Thx

Comment: Cloud means you are using the bitbucket official website, it is the most common approach. Server means you are hosting the repo by yourself (on a server on your own company, using the bitbucket system). I would guess you are using Cloud!

Comment: Also, if for 6 months it worked fine, it may just be that your current App password has expired, and you need to reset it.

Comment: @Arson0 - Thx for the help and additional info. That was spot on. Many Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your login has been working fine for 6 months, I would say that creating a new App password on BitBucket will fix the Invalid Credentials, it probably expired.

Other approach would be to put your username without the domain, for example
arson@enterprises.org would be just arson.